# Definition of $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ norm.

Tags: functional-analysis

What is the definition of
$$\|f(x)\|_{L^2[-\pi,\pi]}\,?$$
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f^2(x)\,dx$$
or
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f^2(x)\,dx}\,?$$

Comment: It follows from $\|\lambda f\|=|\lambda |\|f\|$ that it is the second one.

Comment: Surely you want triangular inequality (which does not hold with the 1st version).

Comment: It has already been answered that the second one is correct, but you should also know that many people, when not using $L^2$ for Fourier purposes, will neglect the normalizing constant, so in some contexts it may be used to just mean $$\sqrt{ \int_{-\pi}^\pi f^2(x) dx} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second is the correct one.

Comment: Then for example, if I calculate $||(x-a)^k||_{L^2[-\pi,\pi]}$, I obtain $\sqrt{\frac{(\pi-a)^{2k+1}+(\pi+a)^{2k+1}}{2\pi(2k+1)}}$?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

The second one is the correct one. By the way, the first one is not a norm. (Take for instance $f$ constant equal to $1$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$, you don't have $|| 2 f || = 2 ||f||$.)